# How to achieve wavy text effect on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I would like to achieve the "Nature" Text effect. [image]

If this effect has a name I can search for it, but I don't know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you may have to elaborate a little. Like do you mean the hand-drawn look?  If so... I would say you got 2 options. Write it by hand or use a hand drawn font.

Comment: @Joonas Thank you for the suggestions, I think I might write it by hand and place it in illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to distort some text. If not, please edit your question and add more details about what you mean by "effect".  If you are simply talking about the writing and how it looks, it may be hand drawn (as I suspect, because none of the letters are the same), or you could use a handwriting font.

Anyhoo, to distort text, you can use *Object > Transform > Shear*. Set the options to *Vertical*, and change the *Shear Angle* as desired

[image]

Alternatively, if you want something more controllable, for example if there are curves involved, then you can use *Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh*

[image]

Comment: I think it's hard to achieve that same effect without hand writing it, but distorting it is as close as it gets.

Thank you.

Comment: There are many handwriting fonts on [dafont](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&text=NATURE) and other sites. I'm sure you could find something similar.